# Run selenium test on Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, selenium, testing, jenkins

I have tests in Visual Studio 2012, for the web site, I want to run those tests automatically from Jenkins, I write a windows batch command

```
<Path to PsExec.exe> -i \\remotemachineName -u UserName -p password <vstest.console.exePath> <Path to the MyTest.dll on the remotemachineName> /logger:trx
```

but no tests are running, if I execute the same command on the remotemachineName  directly the tests runs, but not from jenkins

I put this command on batch File, try to run it from directly on remotemachineName : it's ok, but not from jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "BUILD_ID=dontKillMe" process tree killer
reference : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

Comment: thanks vaibhavnd , do I have to add:<Context path="/" docBase="/opt/hudson">
  <Parameter name="hudson.util.ProcessTreeKiller.disable" value="true"/>
</Context>    on the config.xml ?

Comment: add "BUILD_ID=dontKillMe" just before you call the your batch script . e.g. BUILD_ID=dontKillMe mybatchscript.bat